# Getting function parameters from function name in python

Tags: python, function, parameters

Given a function's name (as a string), can I get that function's parameter list (assuming it exists in the same file)? Basically, here's what I want:

```
def foo(bar):
    print str(bar);

funcName = 'foo';
printFunctionParameters(funcName);
```

where I obviously want `printFunctionParameters` to print `bar`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `inspect` module:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def foo(bar):pass
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo)
ArgSpec(args=['bar'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Comment: That's not quite what I want. Notice that I am given only the function name as a string. Is there any way to use inspect on a string?

Comment: I figured it out. In your case, if `a = 'foo'`, then all I have to do is use the eval function along with your suggestion, i.e. `inspect.getargspec(eval(a))`. Please update your answer so that I can set it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use eval here, just access the module `__dict__`.  Use `inspect.getargspec(module.__dict__[funcName])` or `inspect.getargspec(globals()[funcName])` depending on whether the function is in the current module or not.

Comment: @Evan Thanks for your reply. Your version works too. Is there any specific reason why you prefer it over `eval`?

Comment: @alguru [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `inspect.getargspec()` is deprecated, and you should use `inspect.signature()`

```
import inspect
inspect.signature(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try either,

```
import inspect

def foo(bar):pass
inspect.getargspec(eval('foo'))
```

or,

```
import inspect
import __main__

def foo(bar):pass
inspect.getargspec(__main__.__getattribute__('foo'))
```